# Code optimization to covert list of integers to list of objects in Java

Tags: java, optimization

I have around 50000 to 500000 employee Ids and I want those employee ids to convert into detail objects.

I have done something like this to achieve that:

```
private Set<Detail> setDetail(List<Integer> employees, Group group) {
  Set<Detail> details = employees.stream().parallel().map(id -> new Detail(id, group)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
  return details ;
}
```

But this is very slow and getting more slower with increase number of employee ids. How I can optimize this code? What are the optimization techniques/algorithms I can use to better optimize this.

Comment: `parallel` is  a good choice in case of large number of data.

Comment: I tried this with/without parallel but didn't notice as such performance. Can't I better improve this?

Comment: Can you define slow? 500k objects should not be a problem on reasonable hardware, is your hardware reasonable? Is anything "interesting" happening in the ,`Detail` constructor?

Comment: Use classic thread pool (ExecutorService) and feel into [ConcurrentSkipListSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) instead of list.

Comment: I just did `1_000_000` ids sans parallel and it took 1.25 seconds on my i7 quad running Windows.

Comment: Depending on the dynamics of your return type, you may want to try an `ArrayList` instead of a set.  It was about 5 times faster for me. Especially if you pre-allocate the list.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to avoid creating that many objects. No matter which algorithm you'll pick if your DB will keep growing at some point you won't fit it all in memory. Also the bottleneck is likely going to be getting data from DB (not creating objects).

So try to **re-architect your app** so that the data is pre-calculated and stored in DB at the time of performing the operation in question.

If after careful consideration you decide that you *do* need to work with that many objects a better option would be to keep working with primitives:

```
class EmployeesInGroup {
   private final int[] ids;
   private final Group group;
   ...

   Detail get(int idx) {
      return new Details(ids[idx], group);
   }

   int size() {
     return ids.length;
   }
}
```

Then you can iterate over this list and work with 1 object at a time w/o keeping a lot of them in memory:

```
EmployeesInGroup list = new EmployeesInGroup(ids, group);
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  Detail d = list.get(i);
  ...
}
```

You can make it implement `Iterable` and use for-each loop.

## Benchmarks

Approach that I listed above is at least 20x faster than creating an *array* of Detail objects. Working with streams and lists slows it all down even more. I didn't check with `Integer` but I'd predict it will slow everything down by another factor of 2 or something.

```
Benchmark                                        Mode  Cnt     Score    Error  Units
EmployeeConversionBenchmark.objectArray         thrpt   20   368.702 ±  3.483  ops/s
EmployeeConversionBenchmark.primitiveArray      thrpt   20  7595.080 ± 68.841  ops/s
EmployeeConversionBenchmark.streamsWithObjects  thrpt   20   197.923 ±  1.616  ops/s
```

Here's the code that I used:

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Fork;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class EmployeeConversionBenchmark {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(new String[]{EmployeeConversionBenchmark.class.getSimpleName()});
    }

    @Benchmark @Fork(value = 1, warmups = 0)
    public int primitiveArray(Data data) {
        EmployeesInGroup e = new EmployeesInGroup(data.ids, data.group);
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++)
            sum += e.get(i).getId();
        return sum;
    }
    @Benchmark @Fork(value = 1, warmups = 0)
    public int objectArray(Data data) {
        EmployeesInGroup.Detail[] e = new EmployeesInGroup.Detail[data.ids.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.ids.length; i++)
            e[i] = new EmployeesInGroup.Detail(data.ids[i], data.group);

        int sum = 0;
        for (EmployeesInGroup.Detail detail : e)
            sum += detail.getId();
        return sum;
    }
    @Benchmark @Fork(value = 1, warmups = 0)
    public int streamsWithObjects(Data data) {
        List<EmployeesInGroup.Detail> e = Arrays.stream(data.ids).mapToObj(id -> new EmployeesInGroup.Detail(id, data.group)).collect(toList());
        int sum = 0;
        for (EmployeesInGroup.Detail detail : e)
            sum += detail.getId();
        return sum;
    }

    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class Data {
        private final int[] ids = new int[500_000];
        private final EmployeesInGroup.Group group = new EmployeesInGroup.Group();
        public Data() {
            for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
                ids[i] = new Random().nextInt();
        }
    }

    public static class EmployeesInGroup {
        private final int[] ids;
        private final Group group;

        public EmployeesInGroup(int[] ids, Group group) {
            this.ids = ids;
            this.group = group;
        }
        public Detail get(int idx) {
            return new Detail(ids[idx], group);
        }

        public int size() {
            return ids.length;
        }

        public static class Group {
        }

        public static class Detail {
            private final int id;
            private final Group group;

            public Detail(int id, Group group) {
                this.id = id;
                this.group = group;
            }
            public int getId() {
                return id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "w/o keeping a lot of them in memory" - after the invocation: new EmployeesInGroup(ids, group) ,  if not in memory, where are they kept?

Comment: @DavidSoroko, EmployeesInGroup contains a primitive `int[]` array - not a list of all `Detail` objects. Which is _so much_ faster to work with. When iterating it will create 1 short-living `Detail` object at a time. Then you'll iterate to the next one and forget the reference to the previous object. This will allow GC to clean it up. So only int[] array will be kept in memory for long time.

Comment: Creating and "forgetting" (if forgettting makes sense for the application) one object at  a time requires less memory than allocating all the instances in one go and then discarding them in one go. But do you think your approach would be faster? If you believe it is, would you care to benchmark and compare?

Comment: @DavidSoroko, of course. My measurements show at least 20x speed up _just by keeping `int[]` instead of `Details[]`_. Streams and Integer will make it even slower. I'll publish benchmarks soon.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this. I played with your JMH benchmark and for whatever it's worth don't think that the better performance of `primitiveArray` is to do with GC as it is ahead with tiny sizes as well. More likely it is because the ints are layed out in a contiguous chunk of memory while a list of objects is all over the heap.

Comment: @DavidSoroko, that too. I don't think that objects will be all over the heap - they will also end up in close proximity to each other. But this may be enough to prevent CPUs from pre-fetching some of the data. Also 50K of ints should fit in L2 CPU caches. Not sure about 50K of objects.

Answer (score -1):

In general, a conversation about performance and optimization should include numbers, e.g: the latency you are trying to achieve, the latency you actually observe, some details about your hardware, etc...

Your problem (if there is one) is not in the method you posted. On my laptop, the code below executes in ~250 ms. and even faster (~ 200 ms) if you remove `parallel()` :

```java
class Detail {
    private Integer id;
    private String group;

    public Detail(Integer id, String group) {
        this.id = id;
        this.group = group;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public Set<Detail> setDetail(List<Integer> employees, String group) {
        return employees.stream().parallel().map(id -> new Detail(id, group)).collect(toSet());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> idsList = new Random().ints().boxed().limit(500_000).collect(toList());

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Set<Detail> details = new Main().setDetail(idsList, "group");

        long duration = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        System.out.println("Done in " + duration + " ms. Size was " + details.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing parallel also ran faster on my test.

Comment: You might be faster with a boring for-loop.

Comment: You may be right but it's not my code to change. In addition there should to be a reason to make code go faster - for my money the OP's code is fast enough